# Expected value of tensor products and matrices?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, tensor-calculus, fluid-statics

I had a problem where I considered two particles in a flow field, connected to each other by a spring. The vector connecting the particles is:
$$\tag{1}
\boldsymbol{s}=\boldsymbol{r}_{2}-\boldsymbol{r}_{1}
$$
Where $\mathbf{r}_2$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$ are the positions of the two particles. The deformation rate tensor is:
$$\tag{2}
E_{\alpha \beta}(\boldsymbol{r})=\frac{\partial v_{\alpha}}{\partial r_{\beta}}
$$
From the Fokker-Planck equation, I obtained the following expressions:
$$\tag{3}
\begin{array}{l}
D_{\alpha}^{(1)}=(E_{\alpha \beta}-k \mu\delta_{\alpha\beta})s_\beta \\
D_{\alpha \beta}^{(2)}=k_{B} T \mu \delta_{\alpha\beta}
\end{array}
$$
Where $\mu$ and $k$ are constants. I want to calculate the time derivatives of the expectation values $\langle s_\alpha\rangle$ and the variance $\langle s_\alpha s_\beta \rangle$, which according to the lecture notes can be calculated as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d t}\left\langle s_{\alpha}\right\rangle &=\left\langle D_{\alpha}^{(1)}\right\rangle \\
\frac{d}{d t} \langle s_{\alpha}s_\beta\rangle &=2\left\langle D_{\alpha \beta}^{(2)}\right\rangle+\left\langle s_{\alpha} D_{\beta}^{(1)}\right\rangle+\left\langle s_{\beta} D_{\alpha}^{(1)}\right\rangle-\left\langle s_{\alpha}\right\rangle\left\langle D_{\beta}^{(1)}\right\rangle-\left\langle s_{\beta}\right\rangle\left\langle D_{\alpha}^{(1)}\right\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$
I assume that the time derive of $\langle s_\alpha\rangle$ can then be written:
$$\frac{d}{d t}\left\langle s_{\alpha}\right\rangle=\left\langle E_{\alpha x} s_{x}\right\rangle+\left\langle E_{a y} s_{y}\right\rangle+\left\langle E_{\alpha z} s_{z}\right\rangle-k \mu\left(\left\langle s_{x}\right\rangle+\left\langle s_{y}\right\rangle+\left\langle s_{z}\right\rangle\right)$$
And that, for example
$$\left\langle s_{\beta} D_{\alpha}^{(1)}\right\rangle=\left\langle E_{\alpha x} s_{x}^{2}\right\rangle+\left\langle E_{\alpha y} s_{y}^{2}\right\rangle+\left\langle E_{\alpha z} s_{z}^{2}\right\rangle-k \mu\left(\left\langle s_{x}^{2}\right\rangle+\left\langle s_{y}^{2}\right\rangle+\left\langle s_{z}^{2}\right\rangle\right)$$
However, I am not sure about this last one, because I am not sure if the subscript $\beta$ in eq. $(3)$ refers to the same coordinate as the subscript $\beta$ in the equation for $\frac{d}{d t} \langle s_{\alpha}s_\beta\rangle$ since the two equations were derived independently. My second doubt is what $\langle D^{(2)}_{\alpha\beta}\rangle$ is?

Comment: It is too far from my understanding for me to help, but I can advise you to precise which lecture notes you are talking about, so that one can look for the notations